# Deserializing sessions beans with @Inject dependencies

Tags: spring, deserialization, autowired, inject

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private Long userId;

    @Inject 
    private UserDAO userDAO;
....
}
```

I am trying to deserialize this object but I run into:

```
2017-11-11 10:09:10.470 WARN  o.a.c.c.C.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] - Cannot deserialize session attribute userBean for session 8757DE617838F4D78
5E86BDBFFFB18A6
2017-11-11 10:09:10.505 ERROR o.a.catalina.session.StandardManager - Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass
```

I was under the impression that Spring would handle the userDAO on deserialization and this should work without any modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way but this does the job.

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class UserBean implements Serializable, HttpSessionActivationListener {

private Long userId;

    @Inject 
    private transient UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public void sessionWillPassivate(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDidActivate(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        ServletContext sc = e.getSession().getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sc);
        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect issues on deserialization since there won't be any `userDAO` as such.

Comment: @DanyloZatorsky what do you mean...UserDAO is autowired in the sessionDidActivate method.

Answer (score 1):

It's not sufficient to mark `UserBean` as a `Serializable`. You should make sure that all of its dependencies (fields) and dependencies of these dependencies are `Serializable` as well. When java serialises object it serialises the graph of the objects indeed.

Most likely it fails since the `UserDAO` or its dependencies (fields) are not serializable. Mark them as `Serializable` and it should work.

Hope it helps!